# What is the command to delete an empty folder (no files or subdirectories)?

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using Fedora10 linux. I want to delete a folder if that folder doesnot have any file or subdirectories inside it. I know the path of the folder.

What is the command to delete a folder is the folder doesnot have any files or sub directories.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755689/

Comment: Hi Pascal, The question is not duplicate. In this question I want if my directory is empty then only delete otherwise donot delete the directory.

Answer (score 7):

Use rmdir:

```
rmdir [path to folder]
```

Comment: rmdir will remove the directory irrespective of knowing whether the directory is empty or not

Comment: Sorry rjmunro, U are right. I right. I got success after using rmdir. Thanks alot.